# Visual Studio can't create a docker image

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, docker-compose

I'm working on a .net core project in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.
I've added Docker support to the project, and I press F5, I get this error:

An error occurred while sending the request

This error occurs in the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets (327,5).

Looking for any help I can get!

**UPDATE**

I found out that VS is trying to send a request to aka.ms, and that is where the problem is comming from.
I'm trying to get it to work in a closed network, and because of that request I can't start it in VS. I am able to run it in the command line using

```
docker-compose
```

Comment: Can you add some details: question doesn't look solvable. Is docker-compose work from command line?

Comment: No, im getting this error:
Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget...
I've changed the NuGet.Config to contain only the needed repo

Comment: It looks like connection issue.  This is nuget.config schema: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuget-config-file. Maybe you also change http_proxy and now you cannot access to api.nuget.org? Is 'dotnet restore' work?

Comment: I am able to run it from the command line with docker-compose up, and it is working perfectly, but I still can't run it from the visual studio. I am getting the same error...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the fix to my problem.

When you try to build a project with docker support, Visual Studio tries to download a file named GetVsDbg.ps1 from aka.ms.
So to fix the problem, you need to download the file manually, and place it in the %temp% folder.

After that you need to comment out the last part, the one that tries to download some zip from vsdebugger.azureedge.net.
Then, you need to find your vsdbg version(when you try to build your .net core project, you can find it in the output->build section) and browse to:

https://vsdebugger.azureedge.net/vsdbg-(Version)/vsdbg-linux-x64.zip

The version looks something like this: 15-1-11011-1. After you download that zip, extract it to C:\Users(Username)\vsdbg.

Be sure to remove existing containers of that project(if there are any), and build the project again.

This fixed my problem, hope that it will help others!

Comment: For future readers - there's a more detailed trial and [error walk through here](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/issues/224)

Comment: That "more detailed trial and error" won't fixed any future readers' issues, though.  Rather, it describes a proxy fix to GetVsDbg.ps1 that went out long ago..

Answer (score 1):

Over 3 years later the issue is still valid if, for example, your security sofware blocks execution of said `Power Shell` script (`GetVsDbg.ps1`) when `orchestration` is prepared by `VS 2019`.

There is, though, an easier workaround to achieve desirable solution, than very good and working accepted answer, namely by deceiving `VS 2019` into thinking that up-to-date and accurate version of the `remote debugger` is already placed under the following directory, called later `target directory`

> %userprofile%\vsdbg\vs2017u5

> **Caveat:** This workaround assumes all debugging sessions will be performed with the same OS.

Recipe:

1. Gather required information - `Version` of the tools and target `Runtime ID` from a spill out of the `Containers Tools` output during `orchestration` ie.

> Info: Using vsdbg version '16.9.20111.1'
> Info: Using Runtime ID 'linux-x64'

2. Close solution in Visual Studio.
3. Download debugger which you need from the aforementioned url template

   > https://vsdebugger.azureedge.net/vsdbg-(Version)/vsdbg-(Runtime ID).zip

   Change `.` into `-` for Version.
4. Unzip and copy to the `target directory` (mentioned above)
5. Inside the `target directory` create a file called `success_rid.txt` with content of `(Runtime ID)`
6. Inside the `target directory` create a file called `success_version.txt` with content of `(Version)`

Done. Solution can be reopened now, upon next `orchestration` something like this should be produced:

> Info: Latest version of VsDbg is present. Skipping downloads

which means `GetVsDbg.ps1` assumes now it has what is needed for debugging. Given 'docker-compose` is correct all containers should be prepared as expected.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this back into the light!  I am still struggling in this very manner.  I continue doing occasional searches for how to make the process less manual for every new version, though (basically, every time I get frustrated with it again)